# Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, cloudant

I checked and tried every answer in here but it still does not work for me. when I added ibm cloudant lib in dependencies, I got that error. before that everything is okey. what is problem? someone help me?

Error :

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

my build.gradle:

```
    configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://cloudant.github.io/cloudant-sync-eap/repository" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.oguzbabaoglu:fancymarkers:0.2'
    compile 'com.cardiomood.android:android-widgets:0.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-core', version:'0.13.1'
    compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-android', version:'0.13.1'
    compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-android-encryption', version:'0.13.1'
    compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-javase', version:'0.13.1'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22

    }
}
```

Comment: does your error have "finished with non-zero exit value 2"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

in your xml

Comment: İt does not work. but error is changed, now it is "finished with non-zero exit value 1"

Comment: Regarding this error:"finished with non-zero exit value 1" there are several reason, if it caused by RAM, try restart your device, if it caused by your java environment, maybe you should reinstall.